# SQL Return parameter as Decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure to return the total weight of a bin, it is returning an int, however I would like it to return to 2 decimal places

here is the command that works to return an INT

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[SumScrapBinWeight]

@ScrapBinNumber int,

     @ScrapBinWeightSUM int OUTPUT
     as begin
     Select  @ScrapBinWeightSUM = Sum (CalculatedWeightLbs)From ScrapData     
     Where ScrapBinNumber = @ScrapBinNumber
     end
```

(CalculatedWeightLbs) is a calculated field that is a decimal (Converts weight units into Lbs)

I must be missing something to make it return a decimal but not sure what.
Thanks!

Comment: @ScrapBinWeightSUM int OUTPUT is declared INT. Change your declaration to a non-integer data type (decimal or numeric for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To exactly meet your requirements, replace

```
@ScrapBinWeightSUM int OUTPUT
```

with

```
@ScrapBinWeightSUM decimal(8, 2) OUTPUT
```

You might want to change 8 to different value, depending on how big you expect the sum to be.

Comment: That is now working in SQL-Server! Thanks! but now I'm running into trouble with invalid cast in my C# Application , but that will require a new Question, Thanks Again!

Comment: you might want to mark it as correct answer if that helped you.